# Passing Object Through Parcelable but Getting NULL Object

Tags: android

> I am triyn to implement Parcle data and send it to some other class through Intent but getting NULL object I am new in Android there may be some stupid mistake if yes sorry for that ....
>   Cretaed object and Intent passed on button click

```
    public class ParceableExampleActivity extends Activity implements  View.OnClickListener {


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.button1:
             ParcelData p = new ParcelData();
             p.setFirstName("Kumar");
             p.setAddedBy(3);
            Intent n = new Intent(this,ResultActivity.class);
            n.putExtra("data", p);
            startActivity(n);

        }

    }
}
```

> Parceldata which implements pacelclass

```
 public class ParcelData implements Parcelable {

    private String firstName ;
    private int addedBy ;
    //private UUID guid ;

    private static final String TAG = "TEST" ;
    public ParcelData() {
        firstName=null ;
        addedBy=0;
    //  guid=null;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public int getAddedBy() {
        return addedBy;
    }
    public void setAddedBy(int addedBy) {
        this.addedBy = addedBy;
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
        public Parcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                       return new ParcelData(); 
        }

        @Override
        public Parcelable[] newArray(int size) {
             return new Parcelable[size];
        }
    } ;



    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        Log.v(TAG, "writeToParcel..."+ flags);

        dest.writeString(firstName);
        dest.writeInt(addedBy);


    }

    public void ParcelData(Parcel in){
        readFromParcel(in);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

     private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {

         firstName= in.readString();
         addedBy= in.readInt();
     }

    }
```

> Receiving the Object

```
public class ResultActivity extends Activity implements  View.OnClickListener {



        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
            button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.button2:
                Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
                ParcelData result_p=b.getParcelable("data");
                Log.v("RESULT", "result of Parcel..."+ result_p.getFirstName());
                Log.v("RESULT", "result of Parcel..."+ result_p.getAddedBy());

            }

        }
    }
```

> but the result of the logs are NULL

Comment: Does this compile, without casting to ParcelData? `ParcelData result_p=b.getParcelable("data");`

Comment: @lxx yes it compiles without it

Comment: Ah, yes, the cast is done in the `getParcelable()` method, using generics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to be a constructor. You have to remove `void`:

```
public ParcelData(Parcel in){
    readFromParcel(in);
}
```

Otherwise it will be seen as a method and not used.

The creator has to look like this:

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<ParcelData> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ParcelData>() {
  public ParcelData createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new ParcelData(source);
  }
  public ParcelData[] newArray(int size) {
        return new ParcelData[size];
  }
}

@Override
public ParcelData[] newArray(int size) {
     return new ParcelData[size];
}
```

You also don't need default constructor. The variables are initialized to these values anyways. And I don't know if maybe it causes problems with the framework.

```
//remove
public ParcelData() {
    firstName=null ;
    addedBy=0;
//  guid=null;
}
```

In describeContents it might help if you use the hashCode:

```
@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return hashCode();
}
```

Comment: It's the first error I saw (it has to be corrected anyways). Let me look for more.

Comment: @lxx I have question does the class member has to set in constructor only or can be set like this the way O have did  , No luck till now

Comment: Try setting it in the constructor. But I don't think that will make a difference. I did many edits to my post, check that you have the current version ;)

Comment: If nothing helps then please read http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.de/2010/06/android-parcelable-example.html and http://shri.blog.kraya.co.uk/2010/04/26/android-parcel-data-to-pass-between-activities-using-parcelable-classes/ I remember I somehow got parcelables working with these articles...

Comment: You can also use Serializable, if you don't have critical performance requirements. It's acceptable for a lot of cases and easier to implement.

Comment: @lxx Ok I am trying its not about the performance way only learning practice if in future something comes I should not stuck